# Changing rendering in UE4

Tags: rendering, unreal-4

Is it possible to have Ue4 render the graphics with a black line around everything similar to a cell shaded style, or would that require models specifically prepared for that purpose?

Comment: Can you share any research you have done on this subject?

Comment: Did you read the official docs about [post processing materials](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/PostProcessMaterials/index.html)? Seems to be exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

There's a great post here about achieving a similar effect:
http://www.michalorzelek.com/blog/tutorial-creating-outline-effect-around-objects/

The general steps involved are to create a depth map and then create a material that utilizes that depth information to perform edge-detection on your geometry. This is not an extremely simple thing to do, but it is possible.